# how to dispatch asyncThunk inside another asyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I've created two async thunks:

```
export const foo = createAsyncThunk(
    'slice/foo',
    async ( ) => {
        const res = await fetch('/')
        return res.data
    }
);

export const bar = createAsyncThunk(
    'slice/bar',
    async ( ) => {
        const res = await foo()
        return res.data
    }
);
```

Basically I'm trying to call `foo()` inside `bar()`
Then in the useEffect of react component, I'm dispatching `bar()` like this:

```
React.useEffect( async () => {
    await dispatch( bar() );
}, [bar]);
```

`foo` being dispatched but `bar` not.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Edit1. it kinda feels like an antipattern, but what I'm basically trying to do is to chain bar() and foo(), and I don't know any other (proper?) way

Edit2. based on @Nadia Chibrikova comment, and this is something I've tried as well using thunkAPI:

```
    export const bar = createAsyncThunk(
        'slice/bar',
        async ( thunkApi ) => {
            thunkApi .dispatch(foo())
        }
    );
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? I mean what's your use case. What's the need to call an async thunk in another async thunk?

Comment: I don't see you call `bar()` anywhere ? How did you call that ?

Comment: @Dilshan my bad, bar() is called in useEffect. Edited/fixed.

Comment: @MarcusMelodious I'm doing it this way, because foo() operates on data ( state ) returned/set by bar()

Comment: Don't you need to dispatch foo instead of awaiting it? I'd move the logic into a normal async  function and called that function from both foo and bar

Comment: @LorDex then why don't you just await foo() to return in your useEffect. Save the returned value(s) from foo() in state or a variable and use it in bar(). something like
`useEffect( async () => { const val = await foo(); const = val2 = await bar(val) }, [])` Gets the job done.

Comment: Also, don't set the callback of useEffect() as an async function. Instead, create an async func() outside of useEffect and then call it the useEffect(). `useEffect(async() => {}, [])` is wrong. The async callback can cause race condition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Chaining Thunks

This is not a great design pattern but it *can* be done.  Your "Edit2" is close, but `thunkApi` is the *second* argument of the payload creator.  The first argument is the args that you pass when you call the action creator as `bar(args)`.  If you don't need an argument then you can use a `_` to denote that this variable is unused.

```
export const foo = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/foo", 
  async () => {
    const res = await fetch("/");
    return res.json();
  }
);

export const bar = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/bar", 
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    const fooAction = await dispatch(foo());
    return fooAction.payload;
  }
);
```

Calling `dispatch(bar())` will dispatch the actions in this order:

1. "slice/bar/pending"
2. "slice/foo/pending"
3. "slice/foo/fulfilled"
4. "slice/bar/fulfilled"

#### Separate Actions

As recommended by @Marcus Melodious, it is better to have completely separate actions and handle the dispatching in your component.  If `bar` requires some piece of data from `foo` (like an `id` or a `token`), then it should take that data as an argument to its action creator.

Here is an example where we fetch a post and then fetch a user profile based on the `userId` property of that post.

```
export const fetchPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/fetchPost",
  async (postId) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`
    );
    return res.json();
  }
);

export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/fetchUser",
  async (userId) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`
    );
    return res.json();
  }
);
```

You can use one `useEffect` and look at the results from the dispatch

```
useEffect(() => {
  const execute = async () => {
    const postAction = await dispatch(fetchPost(POST_ID));
    const {userId} = postAction.payload;
    dispatch(fetchUser(userId));
  };

  execute();
}, []);
```

Or you can initiate the two requests from two separate `useEffect` hooks.  Your second hook knows when to dispatch based on changes in the Redux state from `useSelector`.

```
const Test = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const post = useSelector((state) => state.slice.post);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.slice.user);

  const POST_ID = 1; // just a dummy constant for testing

  console.log(post, user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPost = async () => {
      dispatch(fetchPost(POST_ID));
    };
    loadPost();
  }, []); // run once on mount

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async (userId) => {
      dispatch(fetchUser(userId));
    };
    // check if post has has been set and has a userId
    if ( post && post.userId ) {
      loadUser(post.userId);
    }
  }, [post]); // run when post changes

  return <div/>;
};
```

Here is a complete code example for the two hooks approach:

```
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  configureStore,
  createSlice
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const fetchPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/fetchPost",
  async (postId) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`
    );
    return res.json();
  }
);

export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "slice/fetchUser",
  async (userId) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`
    );
    return res.json();
  }
);

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "slice",
  initialState: {
    user: undefined,
    post: undefined
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.post = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

const store = configureStore({ reducer: { slice: slice.reducer } });

const PostHeader = ({ postId }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const post = useSelector((state) => state.slice.post);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.slice.user);

  console.log(post, user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPost = async () => {
      dispatch(fetchPost(postId));
    };
    loadPost();
  }, [postId, dispatch]); // run once on mount

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async (userId) => {
      dispatch(fetchUser(userId));
    };
    // check if post has has been set and has a userId
    if (post && post.userId) {
      loadUser(post.userId);
    }
  }, [post, dispatch]); // run when post changes

  return (
    <div>
      {!!post && <h1>{post.title}</h1>}
      {!!user && <h2>By {user.name}</h2>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PostHeader postId={1} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: amazing response, thank you. I actually went and use separate useEffects before reading your answer.

Comment: also worth mentioning that in your fetchUser thunk you can add condition to check for example if the userId is set (condition goes into options object)

Comment: It would be better and cleaner to put this logic into a hook like `useFetchPost` to avoid using dispatch directly inside your component